# How do I set up an OpenArena server?

Tags: hosting, quake-3

How do I set up a non-dedicated server for me and some friends to 1 versus 1 and such. Also how do they join?

I have tried setting up a server using the `Multiplayer - Create` method, but I was unable to get my friend to join, when he tried to join he'd get a black screen and then be back at the main menu again.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated, I've already tried following OpenArena's official documentation, but I can't get this to work.

Comment: Can you add some details, is this a LAN setup (same router) or online? If the latter have you looked at port forwarding or have you given a global IP to your friend?

Comment: @Angzuril internet setup and im not sure what these are sorry, ive never done this before.

Comment: Okay, how were you getting your friend to join? Was he typing in an IP address? Did it start with 192.168.***.*** or something else?

Comment: @Angzuril Oh yeah, address, i thought that was asking for the hostname, thanks. So he has to enter my ip?

Comment: Most likely. A hostname would only resolve on a local network.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an OpenArena server with `Multiplayer - Create` as you described.

When hosting over the internet your friends need to connect to your global IP address. Determining your IP can vary by OS, but one way to confirm is to check [here](http://www.myglobalip.com/).

Looking at the [wiki](http://openarena.wikia.com/wiki/Manual/Multiplayer) the general command to connect to a server is

> connect address:port

Where "address" and "port" are specific to the server. Example:

> connect 192.168.0.200:27970

If they are not connecting using commands, they can instead use `Multiplayer - Specify Server` and fill it out as below.

[image]

Note that an IP address that looks like 192.168.xxx.xxx is not a global IP address, but for your local network. Such an address will work during LAN where all computers are connected to the same router, but will not allow access to other players online.

The default port is 27960, and does not need to be supplied to the command if the server is using that port.

If your friend is still unable to connect using the correct address and port, the issue may lie with a router or firewall. First, get each player to confirm that they can connect to an arbitrary server. I suggest using [this site](http://openarena.ws/servers.html) to check for existing servers. More details on what you need to do to deal with ports can be found [here](http://openarena.wikia.com/wiki/Manual/Multiplayer/Advanced#IPs.2C_routers_and_firewalls).

Comment: My friends gets an endless awaiting challenge screen?

Comment: @J.Dolan Are they able to join other servers? Or is it just your server?